# Creating custom module: Menuitem SEF links?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I have a Joomla site that I am working on, building some custom modules to control content.

I am using a menuitem field type:

```
<field type="menuitem" name="loc_nav_item" label="Link URL" ></field>
```

And then echoing out:

```
<a href="<?php echo $params->get('loc_nav_item');"></a>
```

However, even though I have SEF urls active and working on the site, this creates a url based on the ID like this:

```
<a href="/101"></a>
```

I am relatively knew to Joomla, even more so with custom module creating. Is there something I am missing here that will allow the module to generate the proper, SEF url?

Joomla 1.7 (required by client...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You need to apply the JRoute function to it - this effectively hasn't changed since Joomla 1.5 so you're fine using it on Joomla 1.7. See the Joomla doc [here](http://docs.joomla.org/JRoute/11.1) for more info for the 11.1 platform though.

So you need to use something along the lines of:

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute($params->get('loc_nav_item'));"></a>
```

Also tell your client Joomla 2.5 has no visible differences to Joomla 1.7 except has a tonne of extra security features missing in Joomla 1.7. He's asking for himself to be hacked!!

Comment: FYI, this didn't work, but pointed me in the right direction. This is what I ended up with:
`<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=' . $link); ?>"/>`